# How can a server record a GET request and respond at a later time without hanging the client?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, client-server

I am developing a chess-like game (using Node, express, and socket.io) that requires 2 clients connected to an authoritative server through sockets. What I want to achieve is the following behavior:

1. User 1 connects to the website and clicks on PLAY button and waits for a match to occur.
2. User 2 connects to the website and clicks on PLAY button.
3. A unique GameID is generated and both players are redirected to a new url /game:GameId.
4. A socket is created for both User 1 and User 2 and the game begins.

What I was able to achieve is the following:

1. User 1 connects to the website and clicks PLAY button. It triggers a GET request and the server immediately redirects User 1 to /game:GameID.
2. After being redirected, a socket is created and User 1 now awaits for User 2 to join.
3. User 2 connects to the website and clicks on PLAY button. He is immediately redirected to the same url /game:GameId.
4. A socket is created for User 2 and the game begins.

The slight difference between these two behaviors is that User 1 should not be redirected to a new page when he clicks on PLAY. Instead, the server should identify that User 1 is willing to play a game but does not respond immediately. When User 2 clicks PLAY, a new GameID is generated and the server reaches out to both User 1 and User 2 to redirect them.

Could you please advise on how to achieve such beavior ?
I guess when PLAY button is pressed, it should trigger a GET request but the server should somehow remember the client that emitted the request and address it only when a match is possible.

If you go to https://www.chess.com/play/online and click play you would observe what I described.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following:

**cient-side**

```
async function play() {
    socket = io();
    socket.on("redirect", function (destination) {
        window.location.href = destination;
    });
    io.emit("play");
}
```

**server-side**

```
var player1 = null;
var player2 = null;
var room = "room_1";

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    if (!player1) {
        player1 = socket;
        socket.join(room);
    } else if (!player2) {
        player2 = socket;
        socket.join(room);
        io.to(room).emit("redirect", destination);
    } else {
        console.log("room is full");
    }
});
```

As expected, upon redirecting the clients to the game page, the current sockets are closed and new sockets are created on the game page which is not what I want.
I need to find a way to queue the client request and respond only when the queue contains at least two requests to redirect both clients to the same game URL and only then should the sockets be created to start the game.

Could you please suggest a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

When the User 1 clicks PLAY, you can to subscribe him at a room. [(Rooms)](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/)

When the User 2 clicks PLAY, he should be joined in the same room.

At this time, you should send to both by socket that they can go to /game:GameID.

When the front-end receive this, you can redirect them.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for the answer. I read however that redirecting closes the sockets. So if the socket is created when User 1 clicks the PLAY button, after User 2 joins the room and both are redirected, the sockets are closed. I am not sure if this is the case but that's what I have been reading, I can check and accept the answer if what you suggested works.